# How do you pop to a specific screen in react-navigation StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to find `StackNavigator`'s to `UINavigationContoller`'s `popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)`.

According to the docs `goBack()` only ever goes back one position, the argument you pass in is where you are going back *from* rather than where you want to go back *to*.

There are no tabs or nesting of navigators just a simple A->B->C->D->E with the ability to go back to *any* of the previous screens from E.

Answer (score 4):

You could actually make use of the navigation.navigate function

> Another common requirement is to be able to go back multiple screens
>   -- for example, if you are several screens deep in a stack and want to dismiss all of them to go back to the first screen. In this case, we
>   know that we want to go back to Home so we can use navigate('Home')

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html